# why plabel replace previous plabel in this netlogo model for displaying patch and turtle coordination?

Tags: netlogo

with the [help of @JenB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391882/what-does-forward-1-mean-in-netlogo-how-to-specify-the-nearest-patch-of-a-tur) I wrote a code to help understand `forward 1`, patch and turtle coordination. The code is attached at the end.

However, I noticed an error: I built two buttons `setup` and `test`, after click `setup` and then click `test` a few times, we will notice some of turtle 1's plabels will replace previous ones, which is not at all intended and should not happen; whereas, turtle 0 seems to have no such problem.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-ordered-turtles 2 
  [ 
    ifelse (who mod 2) = 0 
    [
      set heading heading + 15 
    ]
    [
      set heading 135
    ]
    pen-down
;    forward 1
  ]

end

to test
  ask turtles [   ;; for each turtle
    fd 1

    ;; get patch corrdination 
    let patch-cor (word "px" pxcor ":" "py" pycor)
    ;; get turtle corrdination
    let turtle-cor (word "x" (precision xcor 2) ":" "y" (precision ycor 2))
    ;; get distance between current and previous turtle corrdinations

    ;; get distance between current and origin turtle corrdinations
    let distanceTurtle precision (distancexy 0 0) 1

    let patch-color color                               ;; get turtle's color


    set label patch-cor                                 ;; let this turtle's label show current patch-corrdination
    set label-color patch-color

    ask patch-at -1 0                                   ;; focus on patch 1 unit left to where this turtle is on
    [
      set plabel patch-cor                              ;;  let this patch label show turtle's patch corrdination
      set plabel-color patch-color
    ]

    ask patch-at 4 0                                    ;; focus on patch 4 unit right to where this turtle is on
    [
      set plabel turtle-cor                             ;;  let this patch label show turtle's own corrdination
      set plabel-color patch-color
    ]

    ask patch-at 5 0                                    ;; focus on patch 5 unit right to where this turtle is on
    [
      set plabel distanceTurtle               ;;  let this patch label show distance between current turtle and origin
      set plabel-color patch-color
    ]
  ]

end
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand the question, so apologies if I am telling you stuff you already know. Sometimes a turtle does not change patch with `forward 1`. The longest distance it can travel without changing patch is 1.41... (sqrt(2)) because that's the diagonal of a square with side length of 1. If the turtle doesn't change patch, then the `patch-at dx dy` doesn't change either if dx and dy are integers. Try doing with `forward 1.5` so the turtles always change patches.

Comment: yes, you are right they don't change patches sometimes, the xcor and pcor value actually explain why.

Comment: @Kenny Please ask one question at a time. That's how we do things on Stack Overflow. Your question about freely adjusting the location of labels should be a separate question. I've removed it from this question.

Comment: @SethTisue I see, I will do that next time. thanks